# Server down frequently - Multiple ip

Tags: server, ip, html-select

I've a dedicated `CentOS` server and I need multiple IPs, I've installed 3 ips

So:
ifcfg-eth0 is:

```
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
DNS1="127.0.0.1"
GATEWAY="95.141.37.1"
HWADDR="60:A4:4C:4F:90:01"
IPADDR="95.141.37.85"
IPV6INIT="yes"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
UUID="01535d92-a759-4fff-a80c-3e3637d64907"
```

ifcfg-eth0:1 is

```
DEVICE="eth0:1"
BOOTPROTO="static"
DNS1="127.0.0.1"
GATEWAY="95.141.37.1"
IPADDR="95.141.37.159"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

ifcfg-eth0:2 is

```
DEVICE="eth0:2"
BOOTPROTO="static"
DNS1="127.0.0.1"
GATEWAY="95.141.37.1"
IPADDR="95.141.37.198"
NETMASK="255.255.255.0"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

Where's the error?

Comment: I believe it has something to do with packets source validation and response routing. All your interfaces use the same subnet and gateway. Have a look to this: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8401

Comment: The explain it in the provided link.

Comment: I'm a noob, sorry :(